# Render PDF and DOC file in WebView - Both can be available either as URL or File - Android

Tags: pdf, amazon-s3, android-intent, android-webview, document

I want to display a PDF file and DOC file in a WebView. I tried displaying PDF file via URL. But I'm getting below error.

[image]

It might be because of some authentication problem. Because when I login on web and open the URL in Google Chrome it will work. If I will logout, It won't work.

I tried using **http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url** but I'm getting below error.

[image]

The actual link which I'm getting of PDF file is of **Amazon S3**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error message seems clear enough.  You are trying to access the object using a pre-signed URL that expired the day before.  *"Because when I login on web and open the URL in Google Chrome it will work."*  No, it won't, if you are using **exactly** the same URL.

Comment: When I tried to use the same thing on 10th April 2019 i.e yesterday, It  was throwing same error@Michael-sqlbot

Comment: I would suggest generating a new URL and retrying.  This error has a very specific meaning -- the current time, according to the official AWS system clocks, is later than `X-Amz-Expires` (seconds) past `X-Amz-Date` -- where these values are as shown in the pre-signed URL query parameters.  The device running the code that actually signs the URL -- whether it is a user device or server -- must have an accurate clock and accurate time zone setting.  The clock precision on the device making the request does not matter.

Comment: Let me check@Michael-sqlbot